# Implement jQuery autocomplete with funny buttons

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, autocomplete

In an web application using MVC4, c# and Razor, there is a cool searchbox functionality that I need to implement.

It has 3 stages:

1. type 3 characters and search for result
2. select result from autocomplete list
3. present result as a funny removable object

Here are images:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I know I can implement steps 1 and 2 by using jquery autocomplete:

- http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

However, I have no idea on how to do step 3.

The web application is in my possession, but since the code is not commented nor is it properly refactored, I have no idea on how to replicate this functionality, nor do I know where to look for it in the code.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Take a look at Kendo UI multiselect as this is exactly what you want: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/index (it is part of the free package)

Comment: yes, it is something like that in fact! Can I do it with jQuery?

Comment: Kendo UI is based on jQuery. As it is OS you can check their code if you want to reinvent the wheel...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking on ChrFin's suggestion I made a search on my own and found `select2`:

- http://plugins.jquery.com/select2/

The project is currently using this, so I am going to keep it and give it a whirl.
In the meantime, ChrFin's suggestion should also be mentioned:

- http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/serverfiltering

Thanks for the help!